# Is it fair to downvote answers that use a certain library for questions tagged with just [javascript]?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

There seems to be a trend where some users will downvote any answer to a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question when the answer makes use of a library. Their reasoning is that since the question is just tagged with that, it's asking for a pure JavaScript answer. I recently learned that some also downvote because they suffer from [Not Invented Here Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Some go even further and solicit downvotes in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chat room.

Is this a fair thing to do? Is this a positive trend or is it harmful?

Comment: @Servy why remove that?

Comment: It's meta discussion about the post, not a part of the question.  And regardless, people are vote how they're going to vote, telling them how to vote isn't going to change that.

Comment: I believe there are people that move in groups around some professor, friend,etc... There are some users that act as a SE-police officer... Don't pay attention to them and go ahead.

Comment: just use jquery

Answer (score 25):

If the question is specifically asking for a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) answer, especially if the OP **explicitly** states not wanting to use a library, then answers that use a library aren't attempting to answer the question. In that case, you'd have a perfectly valid reason to downvote the answer.

However, if the question **doesn't** explicitly state not to use any libraries, I don't think the downvotes are warranted.

Either way, this really depends on the question and the answer. Basically, use common sense when voting. Don't just vote because the answer uses (or doesn't use) a library, *vote because the answer good or bad*.

Answer (score 6):

People's votes are theirs to use.  If they feel that an answer isn't useful because of its use of a library, then they are entirely within their rights to express that through the use of voting.

Comment: Yes, people are free to vote as they please. But should we not think of possible long-term consequences?

Comment: @Stijn So let's assume, hypothetically, that everyone here comes to the consensus that this type of voting is wrong.  What do you intend to do about it?  How do you intend to stop people from voting for this reason?

Comment: We can try to change their minds when they add a comment after downvoting.

Comment: @Stijn You don't need a meta discussion to do that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that? Do you mean I should just do whatever I like and disregard community input?

Comment: @Stijn I mean that it is never wrong to vote based on whether or not you feel a post is helpful, regardless of whether other people think it's helpful or not.  If you wish to discuss the merits of a particular post with someone, then do so, but trying to come to meta and say that someone's votes are in any way wrong isn't going to accomplish much of anything.

Comment: I disagree. Often when there's a disagreement on SO and the problem has been discussed at length with a consensus solution on Meta, it is reasonable to provide the link to Meta. I see no harm in this. This is *much* better than repeating these discussions each time on SO.

Comment: @jpp There's no possible consensus that you can say for an entire class of problems like this.  It's just too dependant on the specifics.  Using a library is simply not either always wrong or always right.  You either have a discussion for the specific post, or not at all.  Those are really your only choices.

Comment: @Servy, Fair view. I would also mention that there are relevant answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318411/answers-which-assume-use-of-third-party-libraries) which do not rely on specifics.

Comment: @jpp That's a post that just took *one* specific issue and discussed it.  It's not like that's the only concern though.  Lots of people will consider specific answers inappropriate even if they disclose that they're using a library.  There will also be people who feel that, at least in certain contexts, it's not necessary to include such information.

Answer (score 1):

I see two cases for questions, (I'm mainly comparing with [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) questions, but I think the idea stands. I also agree with [Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270437/is-it-fair-to-downvote-answers-that-use-a-certain-library-for-questions-tagged-w/270440#270440), specially on the common sense part).

1. The question can be solved in the base language without much complexity and as such doesn't require a library:

   - Answers in the base language and offering an alternative with a library for an easier syntax or other helpers are OK.
   - Answers throwing in a library just because they are too familiar with it to remember the base language are downvote worthy in my opinion.

Out of the two cases, answers stating they complement the existing answer with only a library example fall either in one of those cases, and it really brings something or it's just for the sake of using a library. For those I'd use my best judgement as usual :)

2. The question requires a complex or very large function/code to be answered in the base and then using a library is kind of necessary even if not asked for by the question.

Calling for downvotes on chat may make sense if people are willing to delete a crappy answer of the form:

> Try this:
>
> `One or two lines of code without comments`

Answer (score -9):

I think this is a harmful trend. Libraries should be avoided only when the question specifically asks for pure JavaScript answers.

If we do go down this path, this will be the result:

- How can I do *foo*? [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- How can I do *foo*? [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)
- How can I do *foo*? [yui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yui)
- How can I do *foo*? [dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo)
- How can I do *foo*? [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype)
- How can I do *foo*? [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)
- How can I do *foo*? [kineticjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kineticjs)

We'd basically end up with a load of similar questions, spreading answers around all over the place.

Another thing, and this is mostly aimed at the NIH reasoning, a question asker does not necessarily know about the existence of a library or one of its features.
For example, a question asking for help on a problem with code for validating dates and times should most certainly have at least one answer that demonstrates how it can be done with a library, because handling such a thing yourself is a recipe for disaster.

Thirdly, if the answer is technically correct and is explained well, downvotes could deter answerers from continuing to answer questions. I don't think that's a good thing at all.

Comment: The alternative appears to be "how do I do *foo*" with two or three answers for each library and framework combination resulting in one question with dozens of answers where you can't find anything.

Comment: Why would the rules be different for frameworks than they are for languages? Or should we have one question to rule them all? Same answer for JavaScript, Java, and C++? Hey, they all have curly braces, right?

Comment: Context is key. Sometimes in `[python]` I see people using lists of lists to hold 10,000's of rows of numeric data (think of all those pointers). Suggesting 3rd party library `numpy` is not only "not a bad" thing, it should be actively encouraged.