# Should we recommend a jQuery solution when JavaScript is equally short/easily implemented?

Tags: discussion, answers

Should we recommend/give jQuery answers to questions when the vanilla JavaScript answer is as/more simple?  [Example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549773/convert-date-format-in-jquery/26549889?noredirect=1#comment41722896_26549889).

jQuery is a large library with quite a bit of rarely-touched functionality. Manipulating dates using the built-in `Date` object methods is arguably more readable than the jQuery answer.

Then there's the idea that third-party library calls should ideally be aliased in case one wants to move to a different library. Should we be encouraging vendor lock-in? Or is this sort of thinking beyond the scope a simple question/answer scenario? I personally prefer vanilla solutions unless the jQuery solution is **significantly** shorter (like implementing a cross-browser [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)). Is that preference (and the reasons I mentioned for it) objective enough to be worth noting? Or is it just my irrelevant personal preference?

Comment: Curious... How would jQuery help with manipulating dates? Just a poor example?

Comment: Related: [Answering with jQuery](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275208), [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) and http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif.

Comment: Answer the question based on the question and your preferences. If the asker is clearly looking for a jQuery solution, giving it without jQuery may not be relevant to the asker, but it may still be useful to *someone*. In that situation i would include both the jQuery and non-jQuery versions.

Comment: Related: [Is it fair to downvote answers that use a certain library for questions tagged with just javascript?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270437/247702)

Comment: @Kevin B: thats fair. I just wonder if maybe we're encouraging a questionable practice by over-dipping into the jquery cookie jar. The dual-prong solution seems to be the best way to slice it.

Comment: jQuery *is* javascript…

Comment: If a question is tagged javascript with no framework tag, a vanilla javascript answer is expected. If a question is tagged with javascript and is tagged with a/multiple framework tags, any answer that fits within those tags can be posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're more than welcome to have that personal preference, and to incorporate that preference into your answers.  You're also more than welcome to take it into consideration when evaluating other answers.

Everyone else is of course entitled to their own preferences, and will utilize them when writing answers or evaluating answers.