# Why answer questions with code in the context of a library instead of vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, answers

I notice that a lot of times, even if a question is pure vanilla JavaScript, folks will answer in the context of a library like jQuery. I get that this works, but wouldn't it make more sense for answers to match and also be pure vanilla JavaScript?

I get a lot of people love their libraries, but many folks asking questions are newbies who are still trying to learn JavaScript and when an answer references a library it makes it that much more difficult for the newbie to learn.

When you barely know JavaScript, trying to decode the jQuery just makes it more complicated.

They should be learning vanilla JavaScript **first** and **then** libraries like jQuery.

Thoughts?

Comment: -1, not enough jQuery.

Comment: Huh? I do not understand...

Comment: That was a pun (and no, that downvote is not mine). See [our jQuery meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/164403).

Comment: There is a place to solve somebody's programming problem and there is a place to teach somebody how to program.  SO is for problem solving, teaching is done in a school by paid professionals.

Comment: @HansPassant There's more to it than that, including a library like jQuery (plus plugins) to [add a number to another number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif), or alternatively, suggesting libraries when OP specifically mentions that they can't (or won't) use a 3rd party library, is unacceptable. Also, the JavaScript tag excerpt says: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: @MadaraUchiha or adding a library to, say, [pad a string](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141577284765/kik-left-pad-and-npm)? ;)

Comment: The easy solution is of course to mention in your questions whether or not you're using a library, and whether or not you're open to answers suggesting you use one.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha This isn't discussing the case where a/the library is specifically mentioned as not an option, just where it isn't explicitly stated that it *is* an option.  And of course suggesting that a library be added when it's adding no useful tools for solving the problem at hand is a good criticism of such an answer, but not a valid criticism when an answer uses a library *appropriately* to solve problems it was specifically designed to solve.

Comment: @Servy I actually don't mind if you suggest a library appropriately when it solves a specific problem very well and can help overall (I suggest Bluebird to people all the time). It's the other cases I mentioned that bother me, and I do see them quite often (specifically with jQuery)

Comment: Unfortunately, many developers cannot actually write code.  They survive by connecting library calls together, (whether this makes sense or not), and calling it programming.

Comment: Sadly, most developers don't know how to write vanilla JavaScript anymore.  I can't tell you how many times I've looked up how to perform simple tasks and found nothing but jQuery answers.

Comment: In my opinion, jQuery is more commonly used for DOM manipulation, it is mostly a wrapper around DOM API methods that handles the implementation differences between different browsers. JavaScript !== DOM API. Javascript exists outside browser as well, where there is no DOM. I don't think jQuery answers hinders the process of learning "JavaScript", `document.getElementById()` is not part of JavaScript language as far as I know... (*I know, there is more than DOM manipulation to jQuery... but mostly these newbie questions involve DOM manipulation*)

Comment: @MartinJames I wouldn't blame developers for connecting library calls... Unlike few lucky ones, many developers has a boss, bosses gives **very** unrealistic deadlines which makes it impossible to write all the code that puts together a real world applications. Heck, some bosses are aware of the existence of these connectable library calls which makes the deadlines shorter than what is required to even connect these library calls \\(^.^)\

Comment: Why doesn't the OP say if they want generic JS  in the answer or specify the use of no libraries? Just be more specific about the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @HansPassant: I do not think the two have to be mutually exclusive. You can solve a problem and teach at the same time. In fact, I would argue that is the **only** way to **correctly** solve a problem because other wise you risk creating more problems. IMHO.

Comment: @m69: I suppose but if someone is a newbie to JavaScript then they may not what a library is. One can't say to exclude something that one doesn't know exists.

Comment: @Bulrush: See my reply above...

Comment: When you say "answering in the context of a library", do you mean something like "Try this: [jQuery snippet]", where the answerer is assuming the asker is using jQuery even when there isn't so much of a mention of any libraries? Or do you mean answers like "You can do this easily with jQuery, here's an example: [jQuery snippet]", in which the answer provides its own context?

Comment: @BoltClock The first option.

Comment: Thought so. See my answer to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318411/answers-which-assume-use-of-third-party-libraries).

Comment: @TJ That depends on how you define JavaScript. If it means ECMAScript, then yes, web APIs are not part of it.

Comment: @TJ ... "*document.getElementById() is not part of JavaScript language as far as I know...*" what? That is a native function... jQuery wraps document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll (hence the name jQuery). It has internal methods which support implicit iteration for things like event handlers, data collection, and also provides wrappers for modifying the DOM, animations, serialization, and ajax. Obviously it does a lot, but *all* of it can be done in JavaScript and *most* of it is a very shallow wrapper (as in just barely above the native API).

Comment: @HansPassant Solving problems is very subjective and a 1 time thing. SO is for Questions and answers that benefit everyone in the long run. Giving jQuery answers devalues the question and answer as jQuery is a library, that is not necessarily compatible with other libraries. Also it introduces a tag problem, should someone using angular put the angular tag on every of his javascript questions and everyone using jQuery the jQuery tag on his question just to get a solution that works for him ?

Comment: @TravisJ  I know what jQuery is and what is does.  Read the last part of my earlier comment. I did say *"it is mostly a wrapper around DOM API methods that handles the implementation differences between different browsers"*. DOM API methods are methods provided by the environment, if you execute it in environments like [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/), [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) etc it won't work. It is not part of language specification and hence it's not part of *"JavaScript"*. It is just something made available by the environment

Comment: @TravisJ ...think of it like the functions made available by [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) and such. When you use cordova you get access to some functions, it doesn't mean those are part of "JavaScript" language.

Comment: I don't think this is a javascript specific problem. On the C++ side you have the people who give you a Boost one liner... that assumes adding the Boost dependency. On the Java side they want you to add the whole org.apache. stuff etc etc. The problem is, if you have several issues you'll end up adding everything and the kitchen sink as an application dependency that needs to be cared for. Not always feasible.

Comment: That is a good point. Didn't realize it at first but it does seem to be an "issue" across multiple languages.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you feel like a given answer isn't helpful because of its use of an external library, you're certainly welcome to reflect that opinion with your vote, if you feel sufficiently strongly about it.  You can also post your own answers without using such libraries if you feel that they would be more useful.

Clearly the people posting such answers disagree with your opinion and feel that those answer are more helpful, an opinion that they're certainly welcome to hold.

Comment: In an odd way I believe I've even benefited from this.  A user asks how to solve a JavaScript issue (no frameworks) and gets the standard jQuery answer and or the (you should use Angular/React/ShinyFrameworkOfTheMonth)... so I'll provide the vanilla version answer. That said I see no harm in several answers for the user... providing different options to "skin a cat".

Comment: I agree and maybe it is good to have multiple answers but I fear one of the negative consequences is the deepening of the answer pool for an already inexperienced swimmer. How is that newbie to know which answer to go with, especially if people upvote the library one or check the answer before someone is able to reply with a vanilla answer.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan That's making the implicit assumption that using a library is always going to be worse for the OP.  That's an assumption I would reject.  There will be lots of situations where it'll be better.

Comment: @Servy: I agree. I am not saying it is *always* worse. It, like any tool, has a time and place and best use-case. But I feel if a question reigns in newbie territory then an answer with libraries just convalutes. IMHO.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan That's not a premise of the question.  The question is referring to *any* question where no libraries are being used in the code in the question.  Of course, that said, there will even be problems that newer developers would face that would benefit from using a library.

Comment: @Servy: I see your point. Another perspective, libraries come, go, and change often. Most of the time a solution/algorithm to use to solve a problem stands the test of time. Kinda hard to use an answer that utilizes a library that no longer exists. I realize that is highly unlikely with jQuery but jQuery functions/abilities might come/go.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Programming languages come, go, and change.  Should we never answer questions that use programming languages because those programming languages might become obsolete, change, or function differently in a newer version?

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, answers should first and foremost solve the problem and explain what is wrong in the library (or lack thereof) used in the question. Then, and only then, should an alternative solution in another library (or no library) be provided.

Answer (score 8):

My opinion:

If the OP mentioned that they prefer pure JS solution, then solutions should highlight pure JS answer, with optional answers using another libraries (adding information on why they should be used for this task).

Otherwise, the best possible answer should be given, in either pure JS or any commonly used, easily integrable library.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to the asker to select as the correct answer the one that helped him solve his problem. If a jQuery answer works for them, that's fine. If the hypothetical poster doesn't get it, he can comment as such, and accept the inevitably-following vanilla answer.

Future people finding the question/answer may up/downvote as they see fit, with regard to which answers help them or not.

Answer (score -14):

To reverse your question, why would you not want to use a widely used library that would reduce the amount of work, and the complexity of the solution?

By using a library, like jQuery, you are being more efficient. If you are a newbie learning javascript, then part of that learning process is learning what tools and libraries are available to help you. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: By suggesting a library like jQuery for problems that are trivial to solve in native JS, you are promoting laziness and preventing understanding of the actual problem. I've seen programmers with _"there's probably a library that does that"_ as first response to most issues. That's not the message we want to send.

Comment: @Cerbrus Who said the problem was trivial?

Comment: @podiluska I wager you would agree that one should first know how to walk before trying to run. Too too too many programmers don't know the basics and are trying to solve a problem with a library. Libraries are great, no denying that, but you gotta understand the core concepts IMHO. Especially when they use large libraries unnecessarily, like when a simpler vanilla answer does the trick.

Comment: @podiluska: Instead of commenting on my choice of words, how about replying to what I'm trying to say there?

Comment: @Cerbrus He's pointing out a false assumption that you're making, not saying  you should be using a different term to describe it.  By assuming that the problems are trivial, when that assumption isn't a given, your argument doesn't hold.

Comment: It's not a false assumption. jQuery answers are often posted on JS questions, where the JS solution is fairly straightforward, if not trivial. If you frequent [tag:javascript], you'll see it happen all the time. Any way, the triviality of the answer is _irrelevant_. My point that's still unanswered is: __we don't want to encourage the use of libraries for anything and everything, if the language supports the required functionality natively.__ I have yet to see @podiluska respond to that.

Comment: jQuery isn't exactly a library for anything and everything. It's a write once so it will actually work library. It's whole purpose is to abstract the vendor specific cruft so you don't need a bunch of conditionals branching because it's one browser or another. You end up with maintainable code that Just Works. For those of us employed in places where productivity matters, jQuery is a godsend. There's nothing worse than dealing with support tickets because some broken obscure outdated browser doesn't work and you have to address it because it's important to the client and the user can't upgrade

Comment: @user356540 *"purpose is to abstract the vendor specific cruft so you don't need a bunch of conditionals branching because it's one browser or another"* you don't need that anymore, unless you're supporting browsers that are no longer getting vulnerability updates which is of course a huge security concern.

Comment: BINGO Kevin. Clients require that their code work for the client's customers. Often they are people in environments where the admins lock down the software and the users can't upgrade. You have to support that. jQuery makes that possible without spending hundreds of hours coding workarounds for buggy browsers. That's my point. In a perfect world, everyone would be on the latest version of their browser of choice. The real world is anything _but_ perfect.

Comment: Right, but we answerers shouldn't be expected to support your old as dirt browsers and poor security practices. Code for the future, not the past.

Comment: Unfortunately we coders, with jobs where we write code for clients, do need to support old as dirt browsers. jQuery ensures I get home on time instead of missing my daughter's birthday party. I make the assumption (however faulty) that most people with questions want a solution that will actually work on all 10 of the top 10 browsers. I actually skip questions where people specify vanilla javascript answers. I'm respectful :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Obviously JavaScript supports everything that jQuery does, natively, otherwise you couldn't write jQuery in Javascript.  But that doesn't mean it's often not easier, quicker, simpler to solve a problem using jQuery. You're right, I am promoting laziness, but you are promoting busy foolishness. The less code one writes, the less bugs there will be, and the more maintainable it will be.  I'd rather use jQuery than getElementById, for example.

Comment: @user356540: I actually work at a place where we no longer support those older browsers that require a buttload of workarounds. Not having to load a library for simple stuff like array manipulation is pretty neat. In your last comment you're implying users that don't want libraries aren't writing code for clients. That's not very respectful.

Comment: I'm not promoting busy foolishness, @podiluska. All I'm saying is: If it's __not necessary__, don't suggest a library! We don't want to send the message that the first thing someone should look for, is a library. For _example_, if ___all___ the user wants, is to fill a `<div>` with a string, are you really going to tell that user to load jQuery? Just for that one feature? Just use the native capabilities...

Comment: @Cerbrus array manipulation is a core feature of ECMA script. It's not getElementById or xmlhttp or one of any number of vendor specific extensions that only work in this browser or that browser. And kudos to you for working somewhere that only needs to support the latest version of IE. Most of the world isn't like that. I work for an agency where the client has to support [throw a dart at the browser dartboard] vendor/version and half the time couldn't tell us what they need to support. They just put in support requests and get angry when someone calls them with a problem.

Comment: Right, but what does any of this have to do with how we answer questions? Why should the fact that you have to support IE8 factor into whether we should answer a question about javascript with no mention of jquery, with a jquery answer or a javascript answer? We aren't writing your code for your company, we're solving your problem, you should then adapt it to your browser support needs.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's true in this one exact case, but when is a person only going to want to solve only that one problem. They're building a webpage, it's going to require a ton of extra things beyond simply filling a div. jQuery works wonders for Javascript and it's generally safe to assume you've got a priori in your project anyway. Personally I'd rather use a library than write a bunch of code myself since I can trust the library to be stable anyway.

Comment: @TankorSmash: if a person wants to solve more than one problem, the question is probably _too broad_

Comment: Absolutely, but we don't answer questions in a vacuum, we understand that they're working in the real world and can extrapolate a little bit, and make the assumption that they're probably using jQuery already.

Comment: _"they're probably using jQuery already"_: That is a false assumption. An answer should work with whatever technologies are used in the question, or the question is tagged with. If there's _no_ hint the OP is using jQuery, don't post an jQuery answer. Same for any other library.

Comment: Everything has a cost.  Just because you're writing less code (by offloading the work to a library that's abstracting everything away for you) does not mean you're writing more efficient code.  In terms of JavaScript, the user has to download all of those extra dependencies, then they have to run them.  Both of these things have real costs to the user, particularly mobile users (having to pay to download unnecessary libraries, draining the battery faster by interpreting more code, etc.).  Is that really worth being able to write 2 less lines of code?

Answer (score -16):

The problem with vanilla javascript is compatibility. jQuery (almost always) works with all javascript interpreters (browsers).

So if someone answers your question and supplies a vanilla javascript that was tested and works in chrome, but the person asking the question is using opera, ie, or firefox (or worse, a mobile browser), there is a pretty good chance there will be a problem if you are doing more than alert("some text"), string manipulation or math. This is especially true if the answer includes the use of a library outside the ECMA standard, such as for AJAX, or needs to reference DOM elements.

Using jQuery just about guarantees the code will work on anything, or at least will gracefully degrade.

IMHO there's no good reason to use vanilla javascript anymore. It causes far more problems (10's of thousands) than it solves (absolute 0). So unless you want to chase down browser compatibility issues and spend a huge amount of time doing it, use jQuery.

Here are a few advantages:

```
No need to regression test every control on your page in every browser after a change
Far better documentation
It's easier to do complex stuff
Far more maintainable
No need to test 20+ browser versions, types, and iterations when debugging
```

I, like you, used to be a javascript purist. Then one day after fighting fires related to javascript compatibility for a few weeks straight (a few years ago), I said F it, learned jQuery, and have never looked back.

Vanilla javascript is for the birds. I spend my time writing useful code instead of trying to figure out why it won't work on Chrome 45.0.67123.112p or whatever, but works everywhere else.

As well, vanilla javascript that used to work, will break, frequently. There are tons of users out there in restricted environments that *can't* upgrade their browsers due to system administrator lockdown. Most government agencies, fortune 500 companies and hospitals are like this.

So you end up spending a lot of time doing workarounds for broken browsers if you do vanilla.

If you insist on bucking common sense, specify that you want the answer in vanilla javascript in your stack exchange question posts. There might be someone out there that will answer. Just make sure to post your browser and version, so the answer will work ;-)

Comment: Unless the question is asking about a specific browser, i don't think browser support should be a concern on SO. it's the developer's job to make it work in their browser stack. I shouldn't be expected to provide an answer that will work in IE8 after just copy/pasting it unless the question is specifically asking about IE8.

Comment: The key i think with your answer is this: *"(a few years ago)"* a LOT has changed in the past few years in regards to browser support. jQuery doesn't really bring much to the table anymore when using browsers that are still supported by their vendors (aka IE9, 11, latest -1 for firefox/chrome, etc)

Comment: @use I had to check you weren't my brother as that is his argument. Let me ask, what happens when a library is retired, or the function in a library is retired? Now the answer becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Fork it and continue development? jQuery is so widely used that someone would do it. If they didn't, I would.

What happens when browser developers break stuff, which they do all the time?

As an agency developer, where compatibility and productivity are paramount, jQuery, at least to me, is the right tool for the job.

Comment: You would maintain jQuery? On your own? Good luck. 5 years ago, I'd have upvoted this answer. Not today. This answer is unrealistically pessimistic about the state of today's browsers. You even go as far as claiming that using a library is common sense, while it should be nothing more than a fallback. ___Libraries aren't the first thing you should look at___ if you want to program something.

Comment: The problem in this answer are statements like: _"there will be a problem if you are doing more than alert("some text"), string manipulation or math."_ _"there's no good reason to use vanilla javascript anymore. It causes far more problems"_ _"Here are a few advantages:"_ (Basically all of the provided reasons) _"Vanilla javascript is for the birds."_ _"writing useful code instead of <...>"_ _"vanilla javascript that used to work, will break, frequently."_ _"workarounds for broken browsers if you do vanilla."_ All of those are exaggerated or nonsense. They are enabling crap browsers.