# Is "Why are you using this library?" a valid comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I have faced this issue many times. When I asked my fellow responders in `[python]` tag, I found conflicting opinions, so I am asking a wider audience for a cross-language consensus.

Based on previous Meta answers ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321320/9209546), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318411/9209546)), it is valid to use 3rd party libraries provided you are explicit and do not conflict with OP's requirements. I assume those two answers are valid and supported today.

On more than a few occasions, I use `[numpy]` / `[pandas]` to provide a valid solution, explicitly indicating the use of a 3rd party library, which then attracts the comment, "Why do you use a library when you can do this without any dependencies?" Once, I was even *downvoted* for using `collections.Counter` (part of the standard library) instead of a regular `dict` and was forced to justify the obvious.

If the comment is not from OP, in which case I think it is good practice to respond, is it appropriate to flag such a comment to remove it as "in need of moderator attention"? It's tedious to justify using a library each time it is used, *especially* if it is part of the standard library. Leaving such a comment unanswered gives the impression it *cannot* be answered.

Comment: You are not forced to respond. You can ignore such comments.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan. Sure, that's an option. But, inevitably, the OP (who may or may not be familiar with the library) will take it as a valid criticism of the posted answer. That's misleading. Usually, it's a pointless question because *even experts* can't agree on an answer as it's purely opinion-based.

Comment: For reference, the final question which triggered this discussion: [Create lists with different amounts of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592208/create-lists-with-different-amounts-of-random-numbers)

Comment: There are many arrogant and rude people in SO, just get used to it. Grab the info you need and move on.

Comment: Why are you asking this question?

Answer (score -15, accepted):

[Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are to provide three things (emphasis from source):

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the    post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been    updated).

Given the ambiguity of what is constructive, these two comments are equally acceptable:

1. Why would you introduce numpy here? As far as we're aware, speed isn't even a concern.
2. Why not, if available, use numpy to vectorise your calculation? It's a good idea for scalability, syntax, performance, and memory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists) for more details.

Never mind the consequences, which *may* be sidetracking, subjectivity, opinion-based discussions. These are considered constructive criticisms and will not be moderated.

Comment: You don't need to post a new answer to just repeat what two other answers are already saying.

Comment: @Servy, the correct response would be for you to *flag* this answer if you believe it is plagiarism. Only downvote if you disagree with it. Good luck!

Comment: As is stated in [this answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365505/), it's actually appropriate to post a comment with constructive criticism of an answer.  Users are not in fact prohibited from posting comments explaining problems with a post that the author should address.  If you are unwilling to listen to the criticism, or to attempt to address it, that is your prerogative.

Comment: @Servy, as constructive criticism on your comment, please reread both answers and study the differences. You will find there is a significant difference in tone and content.

Comment: I have compared the answers.  I don't see any meaningful differences in *either* tone *or* content.  I guess, upon comparing them for a 4th time, the tone of your last paragraph is honestly rather dismissive of the comments and attempting to make a little snide jab at them, whereas the other answer's tone indicates that they think it's useful.  I don't consider that snide jab a useful addition requiring a new answer.

Comment: @Servy, then we can agree to disagree :). Feel free to flag if you think this is in need of moderator attention. Or post a Meta on this Meta. I think that's about all the options available, if you care.

Answer (score 13):

That is most definitely not *in need of moderator intervention*!

People can have any opinion they want about the justifiability of using libraries, and as long as they stay nice when saying it is a great waste of moderator time to use such a flag. Even if they don't, normal "rude or abusive" flags will do.

---

Generally, flagging a comment should not be done on the basis of disagreement. That is not fair, neither is it the goal of flags, nor the general goal of moderation.

Comment: This was a, possibly clumsy, attempt at not making you feel attacked. It *seems*, from your idea of flagging the comment, that you are trying to make it disappear. Appearances can be misleading.

Answer (score 10):

[Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are there to do three things (emphasis mine):

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - **Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post**;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Looking at the comment in question,

> Why would you introduce numpy here? As far as we're aware, speed isn't even a concern.

I personally see this as constructive criticism, which you responded to appropriately by editing your answer to include justification for your choice to use `numpy`.

As the comment fits in the guidelines for using comments, this particular comment does not need intervention.

Comment: Can you therefore confirm, for every question that has an inefficient list-of-list-of-numbers solution, I am permitted to add the comment, "Why not, if available, use numpy to vectorise your calculation? It's a good idea for scalability, syntax, performance, and memory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists) for more details."? Seems like I should have this at hand for *most* of these questions on SO.

Comment: Absolutely correct. That sounds like reasonable feedback.