# My answer was deleted, but I'm not sure why

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Equal height image grid that fills up width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029282/equal-height-image-grid-that-fills-up-width-of-container/70098714#70098714)*

I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow and yesterday I posted an answer to a question. Two hours later that answer was deleted with some explanations in comments and I don't really agree with those comments, but I might be wrong. I would like to better understand this deletion if it's possible.

The first comment on my answer is: *"...you should not hijack the question and post your own question as an answer"*.
I don't understand that because I didn't ask any question on my answer. What I did is paraphrase the question to make the goals clear.

What I paraphrased:

- 1 or x rows with multiple images : *1 row with 3 images inside. 1 row with 2 images inside.*
- the size of all images is not known in advance : *All the images don't have consistent width and height*
- equal height of each images in a row : *Equal height image grid*
- all the images must have the same width as the container: *Equal height image grid that fills up width of container*
- And the images have to maintain their cropping and aspect-ratio : *I need the images to maintain their cropping and aspect-ratio*

The second comment is: *"This does not really answer the question. ..."*
I posted a [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) and the result seems to answer the original question.
*"... If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question..."*

For me, it's not a different question, but I'm really open to discussion, and maybe I missed something there.

[An image of the question and answer for <10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78hJ4.png)

Comment: The first part of the answer reads like you are trying to ask a new question. I think this has mislead people in to thinking this was not an answer.

Comment: The text at the top of your answer certainly makes it read like a question, *not* an answer. Saying "you had the same problem" and you "didn't find any solution" are all phrases that "*me too*" answers tend to use (A *me too* answer is where someone has used an answer to state they are having the same problem and don't provide an actual answer). If it *is* an answer, it appears to have easily mislead at least 3 people; I personally suspect I would have been too. I would suggest rewording the top to not use such language, which is noise, and then hopefully it'll get some undelete votes.

Comment: This is a fine answer and shouldn't have been deleted. Reviewers are supposed to read the whole answer, not a part of it.

Comment: We've undeleted the answer. I've also flagged the comments under it as no longer needed as it's clear it is an answer.

Comment: @ayhan I really wouldn't blame the reviewers for this. This is the original post before edits https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70098714/1. Then the answer says "I'm trying to achieve the same thing" ... "Until now, I didn't find any solution with CSS. Here's a solution using jQuery :" And the question is about CSS, not jQuery. I would have deleted this too.

Comment: @Lundin the question has a JavaScript tag and the OP explicitly says a JavaScript solution is OK so I don't see why a JavaScript solution would be a problem.

Comment: @Lundin the OP has amended the answer since, based on the feedback here; the OP is quite open about the original content of their answer in the question.

Comment: @ayhan because jQuery is not JavaScript.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Better tell the people who maintain jQuery that so they stop writing jQuery in JavaScript ;-P.

Comment: @Larnu Yes the answer is fine _now_ but it wasn't in revision 1. The delete reviews were correct, in my opinion.

Comment: The position that some merely deceiving meta-commentary in an answer would merit the deletion of the entire answer has a strong "throwing the baby with the bathwater" sentiment.

Comment: I disagree, @Lundin, the answer *was* an answer, but it was worded poorly so that it could easily be interpreted as a "me too" answer, as I explain in my answer below.

Comment: @Larnu Also, giving an answer about a different technology than the one mentioned in the question makes the answer _off-topic_, which is cause for deletion.

Comment: An answer can't be off-topic, @Lundin ; questions can be off topic, but answers not. Answering in the wrong dialect/language is cause for downvoting, not deletion; it is still an answer just not a helpful one.

Comment: @Larnu Umm that doesn't make any sense. Questions can't be off-topic since they define the topic. Answers can obviously be off-topic. If you ask a Javascript question and I give a detailed answer about the food preferences of fluffy ponies, my answer is blatantly off-topic and should be deleted.

Comment: Folks, let's drop the "jQuery is not JavaScript" reasoning here. jQuery is a JavaScript library for DOM manipulation. Many people will not want to include it, and many should even not include it at all, but that alone does not mean its use in an answer does not constitute an answer. [This is not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321319/why-answer-questions-with-code-in-the-context-of-a-library-instead-of-vanilla-ja) [a new concept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275208/answering-with-jquery).

Comment: *"Questions can't be off-topic"* @Lundin, what? Have you never opened the Close dialogue window? There's a multiple off-topic options for questions. *"About general computing hardware and software"* and *"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"* are 2 examples of off-topic questions.

Comment: @Lundin I WOULD blame those people and some here in the comments that say that they wouldn't notice. If you don't want to bother with reading long answer in full, the only proper action is to press "Skip". I see too many comments that show that reviewers obviously didn't read reviewed content in full nowadays.

Comment: @Larnu "*answering in the wrong dialect/language is cause for downvoting, not deletion*" It is cause for both. If you think a post is downvote-worthy, that implies it is not useful. Should we not delete content that is not useful?

Comment: It might still be useful to someone though, @TylerH . An answer in the wrong dialect/language might still be a correct and well formatted answer for that dialect. I'm not a fan of voting deleting good content, even if it's not useful (I realise those appear to contradict each other but they aren't; good and usefulness aren't always related).

Comment: To be honest, I'd consider deleting an answer just for the use of jQuery. I bet if there was a joke answer where the problem is solved by a Turing machine, it would be removed as not a real answer, and using jQuery in 2021 (when most of its functionality became standard browser API) is nothing short of joke.

Comment: @Larnu If you surmise that an answer might still be useful to someone else, you shouldn't downvote it.

Comment: That isn't how votes work, @TylerH . You vote on if you *think* answer is useful/helpful, not if you think it might be for someone else. If we did the latter, it's likely no answer would be downvoted, no matter how poor some of them are.

Comment: @Larnu The prompt says useful or not useful. It doesn't say anything about anyone else. If you think it *could* be useful, why would you downvote it? I'd have to go downvote 10 million answers if I prescribed to your philosophy because they aren't personally relevant to something I'm trying to do. If an answer could be useful, to you *or* anyone else, you shouldn't downvote it. If you think an answer is downvote-worthy, you inherently think it should be deleted. That's *precisely* how the system is designed, and why answer deletion is locked behind a negative score.

Comment: I cannot disagree with you more, @TylerH ... I will continue to downvote answers that are in the wrong language for the question if they aren't useful for the question; if you want to not do so, that is your perogative. They are your votes after all; I can't tell you want to do with them.

Comment: @Larnu Granted, I didn't explicitly state this, but I will now, since your response ignores it: an answer has to meet the other rules as well. That includes "address the question that was asked". If I see something in PHP on a question asking for a JS solution, that's not an answer to the question, even if a PHP programmer landing on it might find it useful. But even so, that still kinda falls under the "no one would find it useful" because no one is likely going to be looking for PHP solutions to a problem on a JS question (though I do see it sometimes).

Comment: @Larnu I admit I'm a little confused how you square downvoting answers that are in the wrong language with the position you took re: Lundin above wherein "answers can't be off-topic", when that scenario (answers addressing a question via a different language, etc) is exactly what he was referring to.

Comment: @TylerH [so] is a Q&A site about programming; how is an answer  that addresses the problem the question posted about programming, that contains programming "off-topic"..?

Comment: @Larnu Because "off-topic" in that case doesn't refer to the context of the site writ large; it refers to the context of the question being asked. Answers can't stand alone... they *must* be attached to a question, and so for an answer to be "off-topic" means it does not appropriate address the *topic at hand* (read: the question being asked).

Comment: Your confusing usefulness and "on-topicness" again, @TylerH ... I can't argue that any more, I've said my piece; we're way off topic for the question being asked (and I've answered that).

Comment: @Larnu No, you are simply not understanding that a word ("off-topic") can have different meanings in different contexts. That's a very important part of the discussion going on here and a big issue across the site as a whole. Context is King, as they say.

Comment: @TylerH , please post a meta question then, I'll be happy to contribute, as the irony is that these comments are completely off topic for this question.

Comment: @Larnu About what? Whether a word can have a different meaning or scope in a different context? Talk about irony.

Comment: *"About what?"*... About answers being "off-topic" @TylerH ... Please, can we stop this conversation here; I have said my piece, I stated this a couple of comments ago.

Comment: I mean, noone is forcing you to continue

Comment: @Larnu we already have a few questions that have discussed whether answers to different questions are off-topic or not: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271207/how-should-we-handle-answers-in-a-programming-language-other-than-what-the-op-re and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268190/answers-that-use-a-different-technology-than-what-is-asked If you really are stuck on a specific word being scoped different based on context, then that *is* an EL&U question (and probably one that has a good canonical already), not an MSO one.

Answer (score 54):

Expanding on my comment, and also [@greg-449](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413287/my-answer-was-deleted-but-im-not-sure-why#comment881037_413287)'s, the problem here appears to be a misunderstanding; that your answer isn't an answer but a question.

I suspect the reason for this, as mentioned in the comments, is the language you use in your answer. To start with:

> I'm trying to achieve the same thing :

This is a classic start to a "*me too*" answer. This is where someone with the same/similar problem has found the question during a search, and posted an answer which effectively says "I'm having the same problem too, but I can't solve it. {Optionally here are my attempts that don't work.}"

You then go on to list *your* requirements. Another indicator that an answer is actually a *me too* answer. *Your* requirements aren't relevant to the OP's; if you are trying to fulfil different (although they might be similar) requirements then you should be posting your own question (which you can self answer).

You then go on to state:

> Until now, I didn't find any solution with CSS

This suggests you don't have a solution so why are you posting an answer?

*Intentionally skipping over the statement about using jQuery for the moment*

We finally then have a large block of code with no explanation of what it does in text (though there are comments, well done!). This effectively was "the final nail in the coffin", and it made the answer appear that the code block was your non-working code where you were having the same problem.

---

TL;DR: The majority of the text in your answer is noise; it's not relevant to the answer (it doesn't matter if you had the same problem to the OP or anyone else). The noise, due to the wording, made it look like the answer was a *me too* answer, which mislead at least 3 people who voted to delete the answer via review because they thought it *was* a *me too* answer.

---

*On the jQuery thing, though CSS isn't my expertise, the OP doesn’t mention jQuery in their question at all. Generally, giving an answer in a completely different language to what the OP is asking about is not well received unless the OP explicitly states they are open to such solutions, or you confirm in the comments. I note that they say that they are open to using JavaScript, but I don't know if jQuery and JavaScript are similar, as it's way outside my area of expertise*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've deleted the noise.

The OP is indeed not mentioning jQuery. Since it's a JavaScript library, I found it useful to post the code, but it can be questionable, yes.

I also keep your recommendation of writing more explanation about what the code does.

Comment: @ThomasBillaud Yeah, posting jquery answers to javascript questions is sometimes done, and also sometimes yields upvotes, but as a somewhat experienced javascript user, I must say that when looking for javascript problems, I dislike seeing jquery answers, because while it looks like "bah you just have to add jquery to your scripts" it's a whole dependency I might not want to add. There are a lot of javascript libraries out there, adding one answer for each one of them might not be worthwhile.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I completely agree with you. Also, a lot of users are now moving away from jquery into other libraries/frameworks like react/vue/angular... 10 years ago jquery was a hammer that was used by almost anyone to solve almost any problem, today frontend problems often do *not* look at all like nails at all...

Comment: (For all: There is an [old meme about jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492).)

Comment: I was one of the deletion voters, and this explanation is spot-on. Apologies to @ThomasBillaud. I _should_ have caught the "here's a solution" part and acted accordingly (edit/comment), but Larnu perfectly encapsulates _why_ I mistook it for a non-answer.

Comment: Later I might post an answer with additional thoughts/suggestions, though I'm not sure how productive that would be. I'm not too familiar with MSO, but I get the impression that post would become a hotbed for arguments.

Answer (score 12):

Although your answer is not directly a solution to the proposed issue, it provides an alternative which might be useful for some, and it is, for all intents and purposes, a *valid attempt at answering the question*. The way I see it, the answer should not have been deleted.

What most likely triggered the deletion was the choice of words and structure when presenting it: *"I'm trying to achieve the same thing"*, *"Until now, I didn't find any solution"*, and a list of requirements makes it sound like you wanted to ask a new, related question. But then it is followed with an alternative solution using another set of web technologies to fulfill the intended goal. This makes it an answer and should be treated as such. Whether the answer has room for improvement is another matter involving different tools: upvoting, downvoting, and editing.

It might also be the case that the voters were following a strict guideline in which answers using JavaScript or jQuery to a pure CSS question would not be appropriate answers. However, none of the comments underneath suggested that this was the case, one cannot read minds, and I doubt that this zeal would be very fruitful anyway.

Final note: writing an assertive answer with the essential portions of the answer while keeping meta-commentary away such as "I also had this problem" would indeed improve it and prevent these things from happening.

See also:

- [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: I don't know about "valid attempt to answer the question". If I were to choose any other JS library, would it still be valid? If I were to use a c++ answer using Boost if Boost isn't mentioned, would it be relevant? Why not, considering jQuery counts as an answer attempt?

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier That sounds like another great example for when _not_ to delete an answer. It is unreasonable to exclude a solution using an external library our resource just because it is not mentioned in the question. And Boost in particular is not more than an aggregation of libraries. It is even less of a borderline as the situation reported here.