# Why is "other action" a "failure of audit" for deleted answers?

Tags: support, review-audits, deleted-answers, low-quality-answers

I've failed an audit by downvoting an answer that was deleted previously (of course it didn't display as such in the audit itself) and proceeding with "Other action" for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086280/936986 and got the famous "I understand" banner.

But I completely fail to understand the reasoning behind treating "Other action" as an audit failure, regardless of the answer content or whatever actions took by other reviewers, so I think this is a bug in design of the audit logic.

If audit code *does not* track which "other action" I took, then it does not know what I did and have no base to judge anything - this choice should be treated exactly as "skip".

If audit code *does* track which "other action" I took, then downvoting should be considered proper action for "bad" content. Actually downvote probably should be a no-op - i.e. once again, same as "skip" even on "good" content. It is not like anybody is forbidden from downvoting, right?

Comment: If "skip" is good enough to pass audit for "things that should be removed", then "downvote" can't be worse.

Answer (score 4):

> If audit code DOES NOT track which "other action" I took, then it does not know what I did and have no base to judge anything - this choice should be treated exactly as "skip".

It cannot be treated "exactly as skip". Reviewed posts are eventually taken out of the queue. Skipped posts are not. If you took "other action" you have reviewed the post; if you skipped, you didn't. Next time you do **not** want to review a post, and you want it to remain in the queue so other users can effectively review it, click "skip".

> *[From comments]* No, that's broken logic. If "skip" is good enough to pass audit for "things that should be removed", then "downvote" can't be worse

Skipping pass the audit because you are saying "I'm not reviewing this, let others review it". "Other action" does not pass the audit because you are effectively saying "I have reviewed this, it can be removed from the review queue".

Downvoting **is** worse than skipping if you couple if with clicking "other action", because then the item can be removed from the queue and will no longer be reviewed by other users.

> If audit code DOES track which "other action" I took, then downvoting should be considered proper action for "bad" content. Actually downvote probably should be noop - i.e. once again, same as "skip" even on "good" content. It is not like anybody is forbidden from downvoting, right?

Downvoting is a valid action for "not useful content", and thus very subjective. For things that should be removed, downvoting is not necessarily a "proper action". Some content needs to be flagged/deleted, and downvoting does not do that, and by clicking "other action" you are saying "take this out of the queue" so other users cannot review and flag/vote to delete.

In this particular case, the answer had [already gone through the LQA](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30418206) queue. 2 users voted to delete, two users recommended deletion.

[image]

So the audit system had a pretty unanimous signal that the post merited deletion.

Since you didn't recommend deletion, you failed the audit. I agree with the original reviewers, this answer was correctly deleted, and simply downvoting was not a great action to take during review.

Comment: "2 users voted" is a "pretty unanimous signal"? Really? Undelete/reopen says that those can be just as "subjective" as downvoting and I've seen enough Q/A closed by people blindly clicking close ASAP as they see any of the trigger words like in this example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413287/. And while answer is of a pretty poor quality it gives a hint in a proper direction.

Comment: 2 users voted to delete, and 2 users recommended deletion. Of 4 users that reviewed the answer, 4 indicated it needed to be deleted. It was an unanimous result when you got the audit, yes.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov no user that evaluated that post said "not to delete", all of them did the analogous vote to delete. That's unanimous.

Comment: @Braiam Except for Oleg, of course. I do see this particular audit as being slightly more open to interpretation than your standard obviously this should be deleted review.

Comment: @Braiam I still don't get why downvote for bad content is bad. Either you go to extreme or you're not good enough?

Comment: It's about the objective of the review queue. It's designed to deal with content that should be removed. By not downvoting you are not only not dealing with the issue, but not letting other users to deal with it (because "other action", again, counts as a "review action", and can eventually push an item out of the review queue).

Comment: @yivi "not downvoting"? What are you talking about? The entire question is about downvoting. And no, it is designed to deal with improving content with removal being only one of options. Also, the longer I think about the original problem myself and longer I try to piece your logic, the less I understand what exactly supposed point of "other action" selection SUPPOSED to be? Is that a button that simply never should be touched?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov on audits, it's probably a good idea to not use other. Skip is far safer

Comment: @KevinB That's the idea I have by now. But that only means that this choice is useless and should be removed to not confuse people.

Comment: Sorry, @Oleg. That "not" is obviously a mistake. What I meant is "by downvoting and choosing _other action". And yes, the queue is meant to deal with the removal of content that needs removed. "Other action" is for content that should not be removed. Maybe it's poor, but it does not need to be deleted. It's pretty simple: only pick 'other action' for stuff that can be safely removed from the queue because it does not need to be deleted, but could benefit from 'other action'.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov not using other at all would be a valid strategy. It forces you to visit the link if you want to take a different action, which in turn will make audits obvious. Skip then becomes the quickest way past the audit.

Comment: "Downvoting is worse than skipping if you couple if with clicking "other action"". If that's true, then don't allow the option at all. That's not an audit problem, that's a process problem. Maybe that deserves its own question to be raised as a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug, @ouflak. "Other action" means "reviewed". If one does not one to review a task, one should click "skip".

Comment: @ouflak it was a "bug" until yivi edited it to "support" at his own accord. yivi, Can you name me a single reason to ever click "Other action" under current assumptions?

Comment: Yes, @Oleg. As mentioned it before: if you think the answer **does not need to be deleted**, but could benefit from _other actions_, use "Other Action". In this specific case, the answer needed to be deleted, so using "other action" was a failure. "Other action" is also fine if you _flag_ the question, and then you select "other action".

Comment: "Other action" would also be acceptable for "known good" audits if you upvoted, for example.

Comment: @yivi, I've actually failed an audit, on a highly voted answer, for upvoting and hitting "Other action". That doesn't seem right....

Comment: If that happened, **that** would be a bug, @ouflak. But that's not what happened here. (Unless that "highly upvoted answer was also deleted for some other reason, but I assume that was not the case).

Comment: @yivi, I'll track down the audit. Wasn't that long ago.

Comment: @yivi, Bit trickier to find old audits than I thought. I've got a pretty high pass rate, so I may take on for the team and fail one in that manner. Basically, it was a great answer. I upvoted. Clicked "Other Action". I assumed that it must have had some severe problem that I didn't easily spot. But it had 15 upvotes. Bit puzzled. Also odd, my own upvote wasn't counted. In fact I've noticed, that no votes count on any of the audits, which also seems quirky to me. So I think the system got confused somewhere. Won't be long now 'til I get another audit.