# Lots of JavaScript questions closed as duplicates of jQuery questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've seen this quite a few times lately, especially around high ranking questions. Here is a good example:

*[How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396)* is closed as a duplicate of *[Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171)*.

The first is tagged as a pure JavaScript question, and the second is a jQuery question and has a jQuery answer. This means the second is of limited use if the person looking for an answer does not want to use jQuery (these people do exist it turns out!).

Shouldn't this be discouraged and the original re-opened? I mean you don't see this with other JavaScript frameworks. No one closes a JavaScript question with an [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) duplicate.

This is one incident, but I have definitely seen quite a few of these.

Comment: Answering all JavaScript questions with "use jQuery" is [somewhat of a meme around here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif). I don't use either of those things, but I can only imagine that if all C++ questions were closed as dupes of "use Qt", that would be very inappropriate and frustrating. (See also: [Merge javascript and jquery tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227827/merge-javascript-and-jquery-tags))

Comment: I mean... the answer is pretty damn close to the same that it would be without jquery... I don't see the problem.

Comment: The issue is jQuery isn't Javascript. In the same way that Angular or knockout or any othe rlibrary. If I don't have the jQuery library loaded, the jquery solution won't work.

Comment: ... yes it is...

Comment: LOL, yes... but it's not **vanilla** Javascript. You need an extra resource for it to work

Comment: Right, but if you ignore the fact that it's jquery and just look at it as the technique needed to solve the problem, it's clearly the correct technique to solve the problem, and is still javascript, still solves the problem, no need for more dupes.

Comment: So I could close the jQuery one with an angular version? It's still the correct technique. I'm just using a different library, right?

Comment: well, no, angular's way of handling it is vastly different from jquery or no-lib js.

Comment: So why's jquery special?

Comment: The meat of the answer is identical to what a non-jquery answer would be.

Comment: what `document.querySelector('form').onkeypress = checkEnter;` === `$(document).ready(function() {  $(window).keydown(function(event){...`? :)

Comment: `if (is enter key) preventDefault()` the question wasn't how do i bind an event handler or select an element in the dom.

Comment: No, but thats an **essential** part to fix the issue. You can't solve the problem without the event binder (well not how it's done there)

Comment: Related: [Answers which assume use of third-party libraries?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318411/answers-which-assume-use-of-third-party-libraries)

Comment: http://vanilla-js.com

Comment: I swear to God I'm going to kill so many things as soon as I get a hammer...

Comment: I don't know jQuery at all, but I thought it's a JavaScript library, so can't someone simply read the jQuery source code to figure out how it works in JavaScript?

Comment: @ThomasWeller that isn't always very helpful. Many popular libraries spread out the implementation across many helper functions. Try looking at the lodash source for an example.

Comment: @CodyGray its more like the "use boost for this" of C++.

Comment: @mafii [I made that analogy, too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339693/lots-of-javascript-questions-closed-as-duplicates-of-jquery-questions?noredirect=1#comment422126_339694). It is a little less of a stretch, but I honestly would re-open if I saw a general C++ question closed as a duplicate of a Boost-focused question. I'd make sure to leave a link as a comment, though, just in case. It's certainly reasonable to propose a Boost-based solution as an answer, but I personally wouldn't assume everyone using C++ is using Boost, since, well, they *aren't* and possibly can't.

Comment: @Liam For open ended community discussion questions, the top voted answer should be accepted/on the top, you shouldn't just accept the answer you agreed to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's remember the basics: What is a duplicated question? I prefer Gille's analogy for this since it's very straightforward and doesn't, not even in the most wildest interpretations, go against the "There are many **ways to ask the same question**, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way." that is included in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates):

> Just because there's one particular solution that works for two problems doesn't mean they are the same problem. But **if every solution to either problem is also a solution to the other problem, then the problems are the same.** — [Gilles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95828/213575)

Check also the [answer given by Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95806/213575) on the matter.

Why is this relevant? Because it establishes a sane rule of thumb: if **all** answer*s* to A are also answer*s* to B, then A and B are duplicates.

Now, are all answers to "How to do X in JavaScript?" equally applied to "How to do X with jQuery?"; I would say: no. Why? Because for a jQuery solution to be valid in a JavaScript question, all and every answer has to include:

> Add `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

Which the later question doesn't need as they are *already* using jQuery.

So, if the question is "How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?" for JavaScript, the answers are:

```
document.querySelector('form').onkeypress = checkEnter;
```

and

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() { $(window).keydown(function(event){...? :)
```

Meanwhile the jQuery incarnation would have:

```
document.querySelector('form').onkeypress = checkEnter;
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(window).keydown(function(event){...? :)
```

as answers. Two different sets of answers makes them not-duplicated questions.

Since this answer is heavy on concepts, I tried to make a query that brings numbers: There are, according to [this very badly written query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/601244#messages), 155 questions tagged with either JavaScript or jQuery closed against questions that are tagged JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: BTW, a stronger argument could be made if we include GUI's to the mix: if someone tells me to use jQuery when I'm using GTK+, I'm going to flip that person table!

Comment: You should see the fit people throw when their jQuery answers to WinForms questions get downvoted. *"But its tagged C#, so you can use the jQuery! This solves the problem!"*

Answer (score 26):

I have a $(**good**) grasp of this situation, as I have a gold tag badge in both the jQuery tag and the JavaScript tag.

I do not see improper duplicate closure as being problematic because it does not happen as often as indicated with this one example.

What I see most are users attempting to answer JavaScript questions with jQuery answers, but that is a different topic. Critically though, they are *very* different answers for the most part.

Getting back to the example question, or both of them, let's just say what everyone is thinking: these are both only around because they were asked in 2009. Neither is a good question, and while the answers hopefully have helped other users (as indicated by vote count and views) the helpfulness may have been from earlier years as well.

Overall, I do not think a post from 2009 should be used as the basis for *any* conclusions, and especially not as the sole post to draw the conclusion that there is a widespread problem of improper duplicate closure between these tags.

*edit*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No query, though :(

Comment: @Braiam -- Fairly sure he used jQuery to make "good" bold in the first sentence.

Comment: Not enough jQuery? I added some in for the holidays.

Comment: JS version: `document.getElementById('post').appendChild(document.createTextNode('**good**'))`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker needs more yayquery

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case, I think the community would have been served better by closing the jQuery based question with the non-jQuery question because the non-jQuery question also includes jQuery answers, and because it doesn't specifically say that it can't use jQuery. Answers to the question solve the problem for both groups of users.

However, just because the question includes the tag [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) doesn't necessarily mean that the question can't serve both groups of users. Take for example these wildly popular canonical questions:

- *[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)*
- *[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)*

They're both jQuery questions. And yet, they have useful answers that solve the problem both with jQuery and without, which is what makes them valid targets for both jQuery questions and non-jQuery questions (and sometimes even angular questions!)

When closing a question as a duplicate, you should take into account not only the question itself, but also the answers on the dupe target. If there isn't an answer on the dupe target that answers the question, you shouldn't close it as such because it isn't a duplicate *yet*.

Comment: *"Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the [tag:javascript] tag."* - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info - We don't need an answer for every single possible iteration of every framework in every javascript question, that's just nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Schematically, the closed question amounts to...

> How to do X in JavaScript?

... while the duplicate target is:

> How to do X in JavaScript with jQuery?

That being so, the closed question is broader than the duplicate target, as it admits more distinct answers. Therefore, it should not have been closed as a duplicate. If the intent were merely to point out the existence of relevant answers in the jQuery-specific question, linking to it in the comments would have been enough.

P.S.: One might argue that the duplicate target does not *literally* restrict the answers to jQuery-based ones. However, between the jquery tag, the "I am using [...] jquery" remark and the fact that nearly all of its 27 answers use jQuery, we quite clearly have a jQuery question in our hands. (It is also worth noting that the closure happened more than seven years after the closed question was asked, which means that the closure wasn't at all an attempt to make the questions converge.)

P.P.S.: In the comments to this Meta question, Kevin B argues that the closure is justified because the essence of answers to both questions is the same. Quoting his comments:

> The meat of the answer is identical to what a non-jquery answer would be.
>
> [The meat of the answer is] `if (is enter key) preventDefault()` the question wasn't how do i bind an event handler or select an element in the dom.

While that is a better argument than the one in Servy's answer, as it doesn't completely disregard the difference in breadth between the questions, it still does not justify closure. It is suboptimal to redirect a reader unfamiliar with jQuery who is looking for a vanilla JavaScript answer to answers shrouded in what is, from the point of view of said reader, inessential cruft. (Note, though, that the scales might be tipped if the question, or at least the answers, were respun to make it clear that the cruft is, in fact, inessential.)

Comment: So, rather than risk accidentally giving someone a great answer to the question that they asked in the unlikely event that there are requirements that weren't in the question at all, you'd rather just duplicate the content again, so that *just in case* the question is actually a different question than what was asked it...would still need to be clarified to indicate those requirements...

Comment: I believe the dupe closure should have gone the opposite direction, only because the answers to the closed one are better and cover both with jquery and without. but i'm against a blanket statement stating that a jquery themed question can't answer a non-jquery question.

Comment: @KevinB I would agree with that.

Comment: @Servy However, if you close "How to do X?" as a duplicate of "How to do X with Y?", you are excluding any (possibly great) answers that explain how to do X without Y.

Comment: @duplode If someone actually needs to know how to do X without Y, they can ask a question about how to do X without Y.  There's no need to assume that that's what's needed if it's not in fact needed.

Comment: @KevinB Closing in the opposite direction would have been a good solution. As for the "against a blanket statement" part, I don't disagree in principle; however, even taking that into account I would still argue that this specific closure was unhelpful, given that the in this case the target question and its answers do not make the point that the solution is generally applicable.

Comment: I don't like closing a broad question with a more narrow question, such as in this case. doesn't mean i'm against it entirely, but i agree it does sortof cut off the possibility of answers that help a broader audience.

Comment: @Servy My arguments against that are pretty much the same ones Cody Gray and Nicol Bolas are raising in the comments to your answer, so I won't  fork that discussion here.

Comment: For example, take a look at this *jquery* question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously I'd have no problem closing any javascript related file upload question with this question, jquery related or not. or how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323 same story. The fact that it is jQuery based doesn't mean it can't have non-jquery answers or that it can't help non-jquery questions.

Comment: @KevinB It can help, but that doesn't make it a duplicate.

Answer (score -7):

If the question specifically indicates that jQuery isn't an option for them, then  yes, closing the question as a duplicate of a question whose only answers use jQuery is not providing an answer to the question; the questions aren't duplicates as the answers don't answer the question.

But if the question doesn't specifically indicate why jQuery would be a problem, and simply asks for JavaScript solutions to a given problem, then it's perfectly fine to close it as a duplicate of a question that provides a JavaScript solution to that problem, that happens to use a library in the process.

Comment: But in the example question, no one mentions jQuery. There is a jQuery answer, but the OP never mentions jquery and the jQuery tag is not used. So is this correct?

Comment: If I'm reading you right your saying that people asking vanilla Javascript questions have to explicitly say, they don't want jquery. Shouldn't this be the other way around?

Comment: @Liam One is not prohibited from providing a solution using a library when the library isn't mentioned in the question.  People ask questions all the time where the solution involves using a library and explaining how that library can be used to solve the problem at hand.  Unless there is a restriction in the question that would in some way prohibit such a library, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Liam Why would you assume, by default, that someone is never able to use any libraries ever?  Sure, there are situations where that is the case, or at least where specific libraries can't be used, but there's no reason to assume that rather unusual case as the default.

Comment: Ok, so I can answer a Javascript question with a jQuery answer. What about angular or knockout or the miriad of other libraries. TBH This is missing the point, so you can answer a question (lets take that as given). What about marking as a duplicate?

Comment: @Liam It's providing a quality answer to the question asked.  Why wouldn't you want the question closed as a duplicate?  If the answers in the duplicate question aren't an option for the question author, say, for example, because they can't use jQuery, then they can edit their question to explain why those answers don't answer the question (in this case, that they can't use jQuery) and the question can be reopened, and is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: Would you argue that this is universally true for *all* languages and frameworks? Or are you meaning for this to apply specifically to JavaScript and jQuery because they are somehow special and closely-related?

Comment: @CodyGray I'd apply it in general.

Comment: Ten years ago - had Stack Overflow existed back then anyway - it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that a JavaScript question was about vanilla JavaScript. Today everyone assumes that everyone has access to jQuery, and this assumption is specific to jQuery only. That's why some people even think jQuery is the language and some yet even post questions asking what the heck JavaScript is and how it's different from jQuery.

Comment: That seems crazy, @Servy. Languages and frameworks are two completely separate things. You are off your rocker if you close a general C++ question as a duplicate of something asking about MFC or Qt or what have you. I can sort of follow the argument that Boost is a special case, because virtually everybody programming in C++ does or should use Boost, and maybe jQuery and JavaScript are the same.

Comment: @CodyGray Why is it crazy?  It's a solution to the problem asked, and if it happens to not be, it's trivially changed and an improved questions with more accurate requirements exists.

Comment: In the same way that an answer in Python is a solution to the problem asked! It's crazy because it's wrong. It's only trivially changed if you have 5 people (or a gold badge holder) come along to reopen it. You cannot expect someone to list all the libraries that they *don't* want to use in a question. If anything, the opposite should be assumed: only specifically enumerated libraries should be acceptable.

Comment: @CodyGray How is that the same thing?  An answer in Python is not a javascript solution to the problem, which is what was asked for.  An answer using jQuery *is* a javascript solution to the problem, so it's what was asked for.  And again, why do you think that nobody can ever use any library except the ones that they've stated they're using?  If they can't use any libraries, they can say that they can't use any libraries.  They don't need to list every library that they can't use, they can just say that one sentence, if that's the situation they're in.

Comment: "Just use this wrapper library that allows you to execute Python code from JavaScript!" It's turtles all the way down. An answer using jQuery is *not* a JavaScript solution to the problem, it is a *jQuery* solution to the problem. If someone wanted to use a library, they would have mentioned it in their question. So yes, I assume that nobody can ever use any libraries except those that they've mentioned. The reasons are the same as "why not just switch to Rust?" isn't an answer to a C++ question.

Comment: @CodyGray *Why* do you assume that nobody can ever use any library ever?  You've only repeated that you're making that assumption, and never providing any reason for why that assumption is warranted.  An answer using jQuery *is* a JavaScript solution.  jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript code, nothing more.  It's not magic.  It's not a separate language.  Not everyone knows every library in every language that might help them better solve a given problem.  Assuming that they would know if there's a library that solves their problem isn't warranted.

Comment: Because it drags in a bunch of extra dependencies, inflating the cost of, well, basically everything. It increases development time and maintenance costs, because I have to learn how to use a new library, integrate it into my process, make sure it is correctly deployed, test thoroughly to make sure it doesn't break anything, etc. It also introduces a dependency on a third-party project that is outside of my control, and there are hundreds of ways *that* can go wrong. Plus, it either bloats the size of my binary or the size of the data I have to send over the pipe, which means slow and cost.

Comment: @CodyGray So what you're saying is that *you* don't like using any libraries ever, so no one else should use any libraries ever?  If you feel that using libraries is not acceptable for you, then why are you opposed to simply indicating in your question that you're not interested in using any additional libraries?

Comment: I'm not categorically opposed to using a library, if there is a good reason. But that is completely different than assuming that all libraries in the world are implicitly available for immediate use. The key is the justification for the library. You could provide an *answer* to a JavaScript question that says, "you really should use jQuery; it makes this so much easier, blah blah blah". But that's very different than a duplicate, because it requires the extra connecting of the dots to justify the use of the library.

Comment: @CodyGray So rather than closing questions as duplicates you'd rather just repeat the same answer to each of the questions?  The whole point of having duplicates is to avoid that.

Comment: I agree with CodeGrey that we shouldn't close a question as a duplicate if the other explicitly states the use of a library that the current question does not. At the same time, I agree with Servy that providing an *answer* which uses a commonly-used library to a question that does not explicitly forbid such a library is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Servy: "*So rather than closing questions as duplicates you'd rather just repeat the same answer to each of the questions? The whole point of having duplicates is to avoid that.*" His point is that it is *not the same answer*. You can't just plug the jQuery solution into a non-jQuery using app without *using jQuery*.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess I just don't see, "use jQuery: <exact duplicate of other answer>" as meaningfully different as an answer.

Comment: @Servy: But as others have said "<exact duplicate of other answer>" won't be the exact same code.

Comment: @NicolBolas but...it would be...

Comment: @Servy: I have no particular knowledge of JavaScript or jQuery. But other people in this answer have made reasonable arguments that a good jQuery answer would indeed be different from a good non-jQuery answer. Take it up with them.

Comment: @Servy: Or to put it another way, it seems you can post "an answer" which would cover both. But that answer would not be as *complete* as the pure-JavaScript or pure-jQuery answer. And therefore, would be a sub-optimal answer. You should not generalize an answer to a specific question, just so you can close general questions as a duplicate of that specific question.

Comment: @Servy check out the [tag:javascript] tag wiki, it explicitly states that if a question does not include a framework tag, no frameworks should be used.

Comment: I believe language is totally different from library. I found jQuery easy and comfortable with doesn't not mean everyone working javascript is looking for solution in jQuery. Lets say i just want to read data from one field, so giving me solutino with jQuery is absurd as i will need to add whole new library. Its likes someone is having some small problem in java , we will ask him to do in Spring.

Answer (score -7):

The answers for both are basically the same:

> Bind an event handler, check if the `event.keyCode` is `13`, and call `event.preventDefault()` if it is.

The only real difference is in the mechanics of actually binding the event (`$(..).on('keydown', ..)` vs. `addEventListener('keydown', ..)`.

I wonder how much value there is in having all of these questions:

- How to prevent Enter to submit a form with pure JavaScript?
- How to prevent Enter to submit a form with jQuery?
- How to prevent Enter to submit a form with jQuery and CoffeeScript?
- How to prevent Enter to submit a form with pure JavaScript in CoffeeScript?
- How to prevent Enter to submit a form with jQuery and TypeScript?
- How to prevent Enter to submit a form with Prototype?
- ...etc.

> No one closes a Javascript question with angular duplicate.

I'm not sure if this is a fair comparison. Much of jQuery is "only" a fairly thin wrapper around the DOM, and most operations (such as binding events) in the DOM or jQuery are conceptually the same. With AngularJS (or other frameworks like Knockout or React) things work fundamentally different, and the answers to those questions would also be fundamentally different.

The "pure JavaScript" question has a bunch of jQuery answers, and the "jQuery question" has some JavaScript answers. There is obviously quite a lot of duplication here.

Perhaps the jQuery question should have been marked as a dupe of the JS question, but personally I'd argue that marking the JS question a dupe of the jQuery one is a good call in this specific case not no other reason than [having a better answer which covers both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977126/660921) (IMHO many of the answers on that JS question are not particularly great).

---

For other questions, the differences might be greater. For example, I don't think questions about animation should be marked as a dupe, since that works very different in jQuery than what you would do in JavaScript.

Comment: "*The answers for both are basically the same*" There's a difference between the same algorithm and the same *code*. Yes, it's the same algorithm. But if the OP needed an algorithm, they probably wouldn't have asked. We don't close questions because answers would have the same algorithm; we close questions because they'd have the same code.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't completely disagree with that, but I would argue that the code is *similar enough* to be considered duplicates in this specific instance, especially since everyone would be better off by having a really great answer to this common question which really explains the deeper concepts, rather than just "use this code"-type answers that plague both of those questions.