# Is it unreasonable to use a library in a solution without first asking the OP?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

In reference to this question: [Group according to a column in csv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653154/group-according-to-a-column-in-csv-using-python)

The OP asked a question about reading a CSV mentioning no restrictions on what packages could be used, but also not using any in their own solution. I posted a working answer using the pandas package.

A user has decided that this is unacceptable without first checking with the OP if they are happy to use that library.

Personally, I think that is rather silly. If the OP decides they don't want to use the library, then they don't accept the solution. But I hardly think this is something that warrants a downvote.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: If it's a good faith effort to answer the question, it's an answer.  But users are free to downvote as they may believe the answer is less useful due to the presence of the library.

Comment: I'd say go for it, to some users a library might be useful. We don't answer solely for OP. But your answer is a code only answer, which is often seen as low quality. Downvotes might be because of that, too.

Comment: Everybody is free to downvote as they want. But I am completely on your side ... this is quite a unfriendly act. Especially if the solution was correct.

Comment: Isn't this why all Javascript questions are answered with 'use JQuery', even if the question itself says "without JQuery"?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the question here is if the js question does not mention jquery at all, is it unreasonable to give an answer using jquery?

Comment: You'll get one that uses JQuery regardless. Guaranteed. Whether you mention it at all, mention a separate library you're using, or even if you say "no JQuery please" doesn't matter -- you will get at least one answer using JQuery.

Comment: Where did the OP even say that they didn't want to use a library? I could see if they specifically said, "I don't want to use a library." How could that be considered implicit? It doesn't make sense that someone would ask for help because they *don't* know how to do something, but somehow it's implicit in their question what answers are or aren't correct. If they knew the correct answer they wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: "A user has decided that this is unacceptable without first checking with the OP if they are happy to use that library." Have they made some threat or action against you? If not, why does it matter if some random user thinks its unacceptable? You're not answering their question, you're answering OP's question.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you are 100% in the clear. `pandas` is a *very* popular library. TBH, I didn't even know `pathlib` was a thing, even if it is a "standard" library.  So not only did you answer the OP's question, you potentially opened their eyes to a whole new library they haven't even heard of. For example, I now will be adding `pathlib` to some of my existing code TYVM! You've answered the question, helped others, gained some points. (almost) everyone is happy. This is precisely is what StackOverflow is for.   Also FWIW, the user in discussion is a gold badger in `pandas`

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Even if you ask how to do something in CSS you'll get a jQuery answer...

Comment: The JavaScript tag wiki explicitly states that, unless a framework or API tag is present, only vanilla JavaScript should be used. Answerers tend to ignore this but the community is pretty good at voting down answers that suggest the use of a framework or API where no such tag is present. There are literally thousands of frameworks and API's for JavaScript. We don't need an answer detailing how to perform the task in each given framework. If people want to know how to use a given framework to achieve the desired result, they can ask how to do that.

Comment: @TinyGiant that's interesting about js. I'm not sure the same would apply to Python, but at least now I know I should go read the python info page.

Comment: @TinyGiant Where does it say that? The only thing I see is direction to use the appropriate tags when asking if your question uses a framework or library, not the other way around.

Comment: It appears that someone misinterpretted [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358696/4639281) to be consensus, even though the votes are very low and it has a few downvotes, so [they removed it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607052/218). I have [submitted an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23317245) to replace this long-standing text until the point that an actual consensus is reached such that it should be removed.

Comment: Why didn't you edit that question properly, for instance, eliminating the numerous grammatical errors? It is close to gibberish in its current form.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I edited it to a point that I could read and follow it. If you don't like the grammar, why don't you edit it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would say that it at least somewhat depends on the language/programming environment, and the relationship between that and the library in the answer.

Consider Python. For pretty much every Python module out there, you are one `pip` command away from making that module available to you. It's not 100% effortless, but it's about as close as it will ever get.

Compare that to C++, with its myriad of build systems, project managers, and the like. This is one of the reasons why header-only libraries are so popular; installation is easier since you don't have to build something.

So I would say that this is much more acceptable for Python than C++ in general. At the same time, it's also a question of ease of installation. A header-only C++ library is more digestible as part of an answer than using Qt, for example.

Overall, my general statement is this: the harder it is for a hypothetical user to use the stuff your answer requires, the less reasonable it is for you to suggest using it.

Oh, and you ought to always make it clear in your answer that you're suggesting the use of a library not otherwise available to the user. And you should probably do so with something more than an `import` statement; put it in the actual text.

And obviously, any new libraries you suggest should not interfere with the ones that the OP is already using. If they're using wxWidgets for GUI work, a Qt answer is just out of bounds.

Comment: The flip side of that is, if I run a `pip install` command that takes 15 minutes and downloads half of humankind's accumulated knowledge, I'm also not generally happy. So even if it's _easy_, the commenter in the original question had a point that heavyweight libraries have a disadvantage. That said, it's hard for me to see how that justifies a downvote.

Comment: I would also say that, besides the question of how hard it is to install something or how heavyweight it is, suggesting a library being reasonable also depends on how likely it is that the OP already has this library installed. Many languages have a set of libraries that are very widely used, so suggesting one of those seems reasonable because the OP probably has it too. There are 108k [pandas] questions on SO and 1.1 million [python], so this would definitely fall in such a category.

Comment: if your company allows you to run pip (as opposed to requiring all those request to go through some IT approval process for new software - even new free software)

Answer (score 29):

I believe that recommending to stick very close to the question sends the wrong signal.

Java folks, for example, might remember Java prior to the new DateTime class, when "use Joda-Time" was the staple answer to users who unknowingly thought they had to dabble with Calendar. It would have been horrible to not point them to the much better external library, even if they didn't ask for it.

Since we aim to help more users than the OP, I'd say it is not a bad thing to introduce them to libraries that could do the job.

As for your specific answer, it was originally just a code dump, which could lead to downvotes as well.

Answer (score 10):

The answers are not only for the benefit of the asker of the question. They should also benefit subsequent readers. So even if the asker of the question does not *want* to use a library, providing a solution that does so is usually a good thing. The only exception is when the asker has *explicitly* said that they do not want to use a library. As this is a site for "professionals", and using a library rather than coding something yourself is typical professional behaviour, answers should assume by default that a library solution is acceptable.

Comment: Even for professionals, there are *plenty* of situations in which using a library is not the appropriate solution to a problem.  It's not just assumed to always be useful or appropriate.  It depends on *numerous* factors, which are very context dependent.

Comment: @Servy Which is why I said "typical".

Comment: You say that using libraries is always helpful, and should be assumed by default to be appropriate.  I argue the opposite.  You need *significant* benefits from a library over the alternatives for it to be worth using, in order to combat many of the problems inherent to using a library in the first place.  There are a *huge* range of problems for which using a library is harmful, and answers suggesting it are not useful.

Comment: Additionally, most of the problems with using a library are unique to professional contexts.  Hobbiests are much more likely to have the freedom to use libraries at a whim, and to not be terribly concerned with potential problems, whereas a *lot* of work typically goes into deciding to use, and incorporating, a library into an application in a professional context.

Answer (score 7):

In general, I believe it's better the answers follow the question requirements closely. If the question doesn't have clear requirements, those should be made clear before start posting answers.

It's not inherently wrong to make out of the blue suggestions for unrequited libraries or approaches, but some users may find those suggestions not to be useful for the purposes of the question.

Of course, that's not always true, and many times suggesting a new approach is exactly what's needed. The devil is in the details, and you have to look at each question and the technology involved in isolation.

> A user has decided that this is unacceptable without first checking with the OP if they are happy to use that library. Personally, I think that is rather silly. If the OP decides they don't want to use the library, then they don't accept the solution. But I hardly think this is something that warrants a downvote.

As long as they are not committing vote fraud, users are free to cast their votes as they see fit.

The only requirements for downvoting an answer are having 125 reputation points and finding an answer *"not useful"*.

I see no comment from any user saying *"I've downvoted you because of X or Y"*. There is comment that speculates that your answer may invite downvotes because of it's *"suggesting libraries that are not warranted"*; but you don't know if that user actually downvoted, or if any of the other downvotes agreed with that comment. The comment itself has not received any upvotes, for what it's worth, so the downvotes may as well be for different reasons.

Answer (score 7):

I do not agree with most of the answers or comments here telling you you're in the right because you seem to have neglected most of the context behind my argument and seem to be convinced that you are correct without even thinking about what I've said.

> Is it unreasonable to use a library in a solution without first asking
> the OP?

## The answer is that IT DEPENDS.

In general, you almost never want to exclusively suggest a third-party library unless you are in a position to accurately weigh the tradeoffs.

Pandas is a very heavy third-party library that requires multiple MBs of dependencies and at least 10 minutes to install from scratch, not to mention the time it takes just to import it. You almost never want to suggest a Pandas answer to a Python problem unless you can accurately assess the gains for this problem - have they mentioned they have a lot of data? Have they mentioned they need a performant solution?

If you are going to go ahead and post anyway, you should at least take the time and explain when and why your solution is worth considering over a three-line answer using standard library code/functions. Your [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56653263/revisions) does not have a single line of explanation, not even a sentence telling the user to `pip install` the library.

Now, coming to the question in question, the OP has specifically asked a question because they have an issue with their existing code (and not because they are looking for suggestions on how to get started with their problem). Your answer would have been fine had it gone along the lines of "yes, this is what is wrong with your code, here is the fix. Oh, by the way, have you checked out pandas?" Your answer seems to completely ignore their original question and code and throws a completely different solution in their face expecting upvotes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878102/4909087) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461246/4909087) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51385871/4909087) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905719/4909087) of users who have done the same thing that were not received well. I can't be the only person who thinks you should be careful when doing this.

TLDR; there is nothing wrong with suggesting third-party libraries, but you should either

1. check that the OP is explicitly open to them, or
2. be convincing enough in your argument to use them.

You did not do either of them.

Comment: Barriers to installing libraries go well beyond just time to download and install.  You need to learn the library, deal with it as a dependency *for as long as you use it*, leaving your application at the whims of it's maintainers to fix any bugs or address any platform-related upgrades that might be necessary, there's concerns over licensing and/or cost, which is often the *biggest* roadblock in professional settings, and so on.

Comment: I agree with most of the answer here which state it depends (it really does, there will always be standard modules/libraries/etc). And in that with this specific case, the OP's question starts with using the csv reader library so other answers should have at least started at that point then add pointers to other libraries if appropriate. As, I've done grouping without pandas if I'm just serializing some data as part of ETL because of the bloat pandas brings (I also love pandas when I do need it).

Comment: "expecting upvotes" - I couldn't care less about votes. I was just trying to provide a solution to the OP as many questions here are just trying to get a quick fix to a problem. If the solution is inappropriate, I think a comment stating that pandas is unnecessarily heavy for this problem is welcome. If you'd asked me to put the caveat on the answer I would have. However, I don't see why the OP should have to wait 5 hours for someone else to maybe give the pure python solution when I was able to give a quick fix with pandas. To me the beauty of SO's design is that is allows multiple solutions.

Comment: I'll elaborate n this: "I couldn't care less about votes" - the reason I raised this meta post was to find out if there was general consensus with your line of thinking or others find value in a pandas solution to this question even if it is inefficient. I wanted to gauge if I was completely off. If the community agreed that this is the sort of behavior that should be discouraged with downvotes, then I would have learned something. In the future, I'll try to remember to add caveats.

Comment: @Dan What really irks me about your answer was that there was nothing -- no explanation to it -- just a dump of code. Now, code only answers in any form are bad, but yours was in a completely alien library that the OP would have to figure out  they needed to install first, and then spend hours understanding how to use it and how to apply it to their original problem (or cargo cult at the risk of it not working on their actual data). And then argue when someone critiqued your answer as not being useful to the OP (or anyone) in its current state.

Comment: @cs95 What irked me about your first comment was it was unnecessarily sarcastic. Why not just state you think pandas is inappropriate for this solution due to how bulky it is. And also that the answer needs explanation. Personally, I still think it's more valuable than waiting 5 hours for an alternative since there is a real chance the OP just needed to solve an ad-hoc problem.

Comment: @Dan Great, but that's not what your meta post was originally about, so it seems odd to me you want to take the discussion in the direction of what my first comment meant or should have been, since the discussion was raised here way after I had made my stance clear on the subject. Granted it was terse, but so was your answer. I also don't get the "5 hour" argument you seem to keep bringing up because if it meant that much to you, you may as well have solved the problem with their code. That also would have saved them 5 hours of waiting.  I don't get it.

Comment: @Dan first, I didn't downvote (I didn't see the code dump either only edited answer). However, *I don't see why the OP should have to wait 5 hours for someone else to maybe give the pure python solution when I was able to give a quick fix with pandas* - I will note its only a quick fix if you can install pandas (I've been in companies where I've had to wait 3 days to a week+ to get access to any new software - including pandas). Hence, better to give solution that matches OP requirements with a "Hey, if you have to do more with the data - have you considered cute little pandas?" solution after

Comment: My post is on if I need to ask OP about a library before posting a solution. Your post here is about my post not giving explanations, which wasn't in your comments, so imo that's why I'm taking the conversation there. Why didn't I solve it using python, the same reason you didn't. I gave a quick solution in pandas because that's all I was motivated to do. I feel that is more useful than having done nothing. Your comments made me feel that you would have preferred nothing. So I thought I double check myself here. Enough people seem to agree with me, so I dont think my answer was so unwarranted.

Comment: And I'll happily take the criticism that the answer could have done with more explanation. I'll even happily take the criticism that in future I should add a caveat before suggesting a pandas solution. And I'll endeavour to do both these things. But don't see any reason not to post a solution as it may well be helpful.

Comment: @Dan I think I've made myself pretty clear, and my answer here is very much a justification of the comments I raised under your answer questioning its usefulness. Every point here corroborates with my comments there. Including the one about you not giving explanations -- I would not have left a single comment about pandas being heavy or inappropriate for the problem had you mentioned the caveats yourself.

Comment: @JGreenwell sure, it may not work for the OP. But by the same token it might work, in which case I've saved someone some pain. I don't see how the solution causes any harm though. So my rationale, might be helpful or might be useless. But it's not harmful so that's a net positive.

Comment: @Dan which is why I didn't downvote but said "best". The point of this discussion is what should be the policy - policy should focus on "best" action. Or - I honestly am not looking at the question itself anymore just the situation

Comment: @cs95 You're suggesting that to make SO a better place, I should mention caveats about libraries before suggesting them. Happy to do that. I'm suggesting that to make SO a better place, you should consider critisising answers in a way that makes it clear to the poster what is missing from the answer. I found your comments unwelcoming and if this had been my first time answering, it would certainly have been my last. There is plenty of value in what you were trying to say to me, I'm suggesting you say it more directly next time.

Comment: @Dan Fair enough ;)

Comment: @Dan "If the solution is inappropriate, I think a comment stating that pandas is unnecessarily heavy for this problem is welcome."  And yet you got that comment and your response to it was to complain on meta about how you're getting downvoted for using a library and that you think it's unfair you were downvoted *solely* because you posted an answer using a library (despite that being a gross misrepresentation of the situation).  You can't say that you'd welcome such a comment *when we all have observable evidence that you do not in fact welcome such comments*.

Comment: @Servy my reading of the comment that I got was that my answer using pandas was unacceptable and there was a net negative to have posted it. That's not the same as politely suggesting that the library is not a good solution. The comment also implied that I had to ask permission from the OP before giving a solution, and that is what I was contending in this post.

Comment: @Dan Yes, you got comments saying that using pandas *to solve that problem in that situation* wasn't helpful, because it's unnecessary to solving the problem, and it wasn't already being used.  *That one answer* was a net negative in the eyes of at least some readers, based on the feedback you got.  That doesn't mean all answers suggesting using a library are bad, just that *that one answer* doesn't benefit from using a library.  Using a library has costs; the features it provides need to be greater than its costs for it to be useful to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Please read the comments to your answer. In your question here, you're not really painting an accurate picture. You were not downvoted for using *a* library. You were downvoted for using an *unsuitable* library. At least according to cs95, the user you had an argument with. Note that I'm not saying anything about whether it is a good solution or not. I'm just explaining what the actual issue is.

I can agree that the very first comment implied what you are saying, since it was

> Where does OP mention the use of pandas?

But in his second comment it's made pretty clear what he meant:

> Sure, you can use pandas to solve any problem but sometimes it is not worth importing such a heavy library just to solve a simple task.

In general, it's completely ok to propose solutions involving third party libraries. But if it is obvious that it can be done in a much simpler manner, you are likely to get downvoted and rightly so. Just as a comparison. Say that someone asks why `print('Hello' + 5)` does not work. The obvious solution is something like `print('Hello' + str(5))` or something similar. Now imagine someone giving an answer showing how to use `SWIG` to write a C function to solve the problem. Sure, it works, but would it be a good solution? And above all, when you get downvotes for such an answer, would you draw the conclusion that it's not ok to answer Python questions with an answer where you import C functions? Of course not, but it was not suitable for this particular problem. On codereview, I did such a thing in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215235/133688). OP was asking for how to improve his Python code, but the core issue was performance. And then importing C can be suitable.

So yes, it's completely ok as a concept. That on its own is not a good reason to downvote. Here is an example where someone has done precisely that and received a score of 31: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562895/6699433

Comment: I've no problem with a comment saying this library is unnecessary overhead for this problem. However, in this case, there were no other answers (OP had to wait 5 hours for an alternative) so I would say that an answer is better than no answer. Also pandas is an extremely common library so, as I stated in response to that comment, I think the answer is valuable and if the OP doesn't want to use the library, no one is forcing them to use that answer. But it still might be helpful for someone else. So I don't think it is valid to state that I need to ask OP's permission before answering.

Comment: @Dan An answer is not always better than no answer. My example with int to string conversion is an example. Note: Again, I'm not saying anything whether pandas is good or not. I don't have the knowledge. But one thing that can improve such an answer is to clearly state that it has major drawbacks.

Comment: And no, you don't in general need permission from OP to suggest an external library, but IF that solution has its drawbacks, then it might be a good idea to ask. But it depends on the situation. I don't know enough about pandas to answer that. But if someone recommended a 3rd party library to get a simple `max(a,b)` function in C (I might mention that the standard library does not have that) - instead of just implementing it, I would downvote.

Comment: @klutt A correct/working answer is always better than no answer. It may not be the *best* possible answer, but to say OP's answer was not better than having no answers is unreasonable.

Comment: @TylerH I guess that's a thing that could be discussed for infinity. But I don't think "there are no other answers" is a good reason not to downvote if downvoting is appropriate.

Comment: @klutt I agree if an individual does not find an answer useful, they can downvote it. But that's not the same thing as saying it's no better to have the option there than to have *no* options. One is an individual determination, the other is a blanket statement applied to all possible scenarios.

Answer (score -3):

As long as it doesn't break the Questions requirements, it is alaways ok to take the OP's hand and lead him to a solution that doesn't require to reinvent the wheel. And even, if the OP clearly writes, that he has to do "this" because of whatever reason, If you think of a better solution, post it anyway. Explain why and be aware that you'll propably not get 15 Reputation for the accepted answer.

Also sometimes OP's wan't to do things, that they aren't supposed to do anyway. E.g.

*How do I parse HTML / XML with regex?*

In such cases, I usually post a link, containing [why not to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and a link to [why don't do it is an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8893/435594). And in this case, there are several good libraries that are perfectly viable to solve the issue. So help the OP by showing the appropriate, easy and glory way of doing things with the right tool.

Because sometimes people tend ask questions, because they are stuck in their idea of how it needs to be done, in the first place. They just don't know it.

Comment: any insight on how to improve my answering skills in the meta environment?

Comment: Don't say anything controversial, and make sure to use proper grammar, punctuation, and spelling. Don't overdo it on the formatting, either.

Comment: @JL2210 thank you. But why shouldn't an answer be controversial? Especially since there is no distinct answer to this question, any controversial point of view should be explained and reasonable. -  As this is my first Meta-Post, I may of course be wrong, thats why im asking.

Comment: I mean if you don't like downvotes. The community downvotes things that they don't like. Still, the bold and italics are a bit much.

Comment: @JL2210 Of course. Thanks for pointing it out. I just realized, the bold part is a bit to striking compared to the other posts.